# Angular routerLinkActive for multiple paths

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing, routerlinkactive

In my Angular 5 project I've got a bootstrap nav-bar menu. `routerLinkActive` does work nicely when the start of the path matches the routerlink of the menu, like:

```
<li [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
  <a [routerLink]="['/entity/teacher']">Teacher</a>
</li>
```

the Code above activates the menu item nicely for `/entity/teacher/add' and more

Problem is, I've got a Kind of 'catch-all' navigation item which contains things which do not line up:

```
<li [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
  <a [routerLink]="['/config']">Configuration</a>
</li>
```

I want this item to highlight for the paths `/tasks` and `/entity/settings`, too, not only for `/config`.

Problem is, I can't change the routing of the app. How do I get the menu item to line up for other routing paths as well as the one in the routerLink?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use a template reference variable to get a reference to the outer routes and then apply the class when they are active. You can either link them to an existing routerLinkActive element or to a hidden one. Here is an example using the hidden method.

```html
<li routerLinkActive="active" [ngClass]="{'active': tasksActive.isActive || settingsActive.isActive }">
  <a [routerLink]="['/config']">Configuration</a>
</li>
<a routerLink="/tasks" routerLinkActive #tasksActive="routerLinkActive" style="display: none"></a>
<a routerLink="/entity/settings" routerLinkActive #settingsActive="routerLinkActive" style="display: none"></a>
```

Comment: I liked this solution, but it did not quite work for my scenario (see my answer below), still voting this up, pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 6):

If you're looking for how to prevent multiple links to gets active, there is a `[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}"` option :

```
<a routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">home</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

For my scenario with a drop down menu (using an hidden `*ngIf` directive, i.e. tje dropdownMenu part) the template variables solution (described above by Teddy Stern) had to be modified a bit for it to work, note only one template variable:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown" dropdown routerLinkActive #colActive="routerLinkActive">
    <a class="nav-link" style="padding-left: 0.25rem" dropdownToggle aria-expanded="false"
        [ngClass]="{'active': colActive.isActive }">
        <i class="fa fa-handshake"></i> Colleagues
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" *dropdownMenu>
        <li>
            <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['user']">
                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> Users
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['team']">
                <i class="fa fw-fw fa-users"></i> Teams
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

That is because you can apply the directive to the ancestor of linked elements, see https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive#description.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

So you should add at any link:

> [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}"

like this:

> <a  routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">Home

Answer (score -1):

as specified there are multiple `routerLinks` but only one `routerLinkActive` show highlight or enabled.for that this works fine
for me.

```
<a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)" routerLink='/rulesConfiguration' routerLinkActive='active' [ngClass]="{'active': createRules.isActive}"><i class="nav-icon fa fa-list-alt "></i>Rules Configuration</a>
<a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)" routerLink="/createRules" routerLinkActive #createRules="routerLinkActive" style="display: none"><i class="nav-icon fa fa-list-alt "></i>Rules </a>
```

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
<li [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
    <a routerLink="/config">Configuration</a>
    <a routerLink="/tasks" style="display: none"></a>
    <a routerLink="/entity/settings" style="display: none"></a>
</li>
```